# Expected Primary Expression before (

Tags: c++, maps

```
this -> gamesMap.insert(pair<int, int (*)[2]>(const &currentPos/3,const &dataArray));
```

I don't think, any more code is needed but I can't see what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Im sorry, I am using C++ , and this-> refers to a inhereted class whos baseclass is a template, the base class has a map called gamesMap , and i am trying to insert the values shown in the snippet into it but i get that error message that i posted.

Comment: What are the data types of currentPos and dataArray

Comment: Also the declaration of gamesMap would be useful.

Comment: You've got like 5 lines of code crammed into one.  Split it up using intermediate variables, use a typedef or two instead of your crazy long pair type, and your problem will practically solve itself.

Comment: What is `pair<int, int (*)[2]>(const &currentPos/3,const &dataArray)` supposed to mean?

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt I would hate to see all the errors that would be introduced by making the program **five times as long**!

Comment: Mankarse was spot on, Thank you. I understand it now as well , sorry if i did not post enough code i usually try to when i ask for help but i did not think it would be needed.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

Change:

```
this->gamesMap.insert(pair<int, int (*)[2]>(const &currentPos/3,const &dataArray));
```

to:

```
this->gamesMap.insert(std::pair<int, int (*)[2]>(currentPos/3, &dataArray));
```

This may not be quite correct (the correct answer depends on the type of dataArray), and it may cause other issues (for example, if the lifetime of the pair in the gamesMap outlives the lifetime of dataArray, then you will end up with an invalid pointer).

---

**Long Answer**

In this line you are attempting to call the constructor of `std::pair<int, int (*)[2]>`:

```
this->gamesMap.insert(pair<int, int (*)[2]>(const &currentPos/3,const &dataArray));
```

You are attempting to pass `const &currentPos/3` as the first argument and `const &dataArray` as the second argument. I am not really sure what it is that you are trying to do here, but neither of these are syntactically correct. `const` can only be used in declarations of objects, such as:

```
//Declare `a` to be a const int
int const a(10);
//Declare `b` to be a reference to a const int
//(in this case, a reference to `a`)
int const& b(a);
//Declare `c` to be a pointer to a const int
//(in this case, the the address of `a` is used)
int const* c(&a);
```

`const` is an annotation in the declaration that adds more information to the description of the object being declared. When you are passing arguments, the arguments take the form of *expressions*. The types of the expressions can be deduced by the compiler, and so there is no need for additional annotations. Furthermore, there is no syntax in C++ to provide such annotations.

What you want to pass is `currentPos` divided by three, and the address of `dataArray`.

The expression that evaluates to "`currentPos` divided by three" is "`currentPos/3`".

The expression that evaluates to "the address of `dataArray`" is "`&dataArray`".

This means that (as in the short answer), you should by writing:

```
this->gamesMap.insert(std::pair<int, int (*)[2]>(currentPos/3, &dataArray));
```